# Script Error UCE0001

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

so I'm a beginner at unity 3d Javascript, I'm  a student of Game Design & Animation and in my Game Engine class we work with Javascript.
I'ts been only 3 classes and this assignment is pretty fun to work with what i learned so far.
I don't have any problem with the assignment yet I'm working on it but like my instructor said the mistakes that we always make is the dumb ones haha.
I have no idea  where is the problem with this script it says to put a semicolon and i did put in the exactly place it's asking for just makes no sense to have one ; in there.
So the assignment is this:

**Assignment:**

- When it is the players turn they pick 1,2, or 3 as the monster to
  attack.
- That players attack value is subtracted from the monsters health.
- It is now the monsters turn.
- Press 1,2, or 3 to choose which monster attacks the player.
- The monsters attack value is subtracted from the players health.
- It is now the players turn.

So I'm not asking for help with the assignment but if you feel like giving some advice I will be happy to take it (More knowledge :) )

So now here is  my JavaScript Code:

```
     #pragma strict

public var playerTurn : boolean = true;
public var monsterTurn : boolean = false;

var playerHp : int = 300;  // Player  Max health
var playerDmg : int = 45;  // Player Attack Damage

var monster1Hp : int = 40; // Monster 1 Max Health
var monster2Hp : int = 50;  // Monster 2 Max Health
var monster3Hp : int = 55;  // Monster 3 Max Health

var monster1Dmg : int = 25; // Monster 1 Attack Damage
var monster2Dmg : int = 35;  // Monster 2 Attack Damage
var monster3Dmg : int = 30;  // Monster 3 Attack Damage

function Update () {

if (monster1Hp < 40){

var playerTurn = false;

}

else if(monster2Hp < 50){

var playerTurn = false;

}

else (monster3Hp < 55){

var playerTurn = false;

}
}




// Player Turn 

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1)) {

print("Player is now attacking First Monster");

playerTurn = true;
if (playerTurn == true) {

monster1Hp = null;

}

}

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2)) {

print("Player is now attacking Second Monster");

playerTurn = true;
if (playerTurn == true) {

monster2Hp = 5;

}

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha3)) {

print("Player is now attacking Third Monster");

    playerTurn = true;
if (playerTurn == true) {

monster1Hp = 10;

}


//Monster Turn

}


}
```

Well I hope we can fix this mystery together. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think your `else (monster3Hp < 55)` needs to be `else if (monster3Hp < 55)`.

Comment: Hm, seems like was this. thank you.